# Построение элементов в линию HTML CSS JS

Tags: javascript, css, inline, display

Почему-то блоки с полями ввода не выстраиваются в линию, хотя их ширина  = 50% и поставил `display:inline-block`.
Пожалуйста, помогите.
PS: в CSS коде есть лишние классы с прошлого проекта.

HTML:

````
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo-block">POMODORO TIMER</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="timer-block">
                <!-- <div class="minuts" id="min" >00</div>
                <div class="razdel">:</div>
                <div class="seconds" id="sec">00</div> -->
                <div class="minInputBlock">
                    <input type="number" class="minInput">
                </div>
                <div class="secInputBlock">
                    <input type="number" class="secInput">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```
````

CSS:

```
@import "http://fonts.fontstorage.com/import/intro.css";
body, html{
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logo-block{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: black;
    font-family: Intro, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #8eca98;
    font-size: calc(1em + 3vw);
    border-radius: border-box;
}
.container-fluid{
    padding: 3%;
}
.content{
    margin: 5% 0% 0% 0%;
    padding: 5%;
    height: 500px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.timer-block{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ff9000;
    font-family: Intro, Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.minSec-block{
    display: inline-block;
}
.minuts{
    position: relative;
    margin-left:0%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    left: -20%;
    height: 0%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    font-size: 20vw;
}
.seconds{
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: -100%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 55%;
    font-size: 20vw;
}
.timer{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
.razdel{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 17vw;
    height: 30vw;
    top: 0vw;
    margin-left: 43%;
    width: 3%;
    color: #8eca98;
}
.minInput{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ff9000;
    font-size: 10vw;
    border-radius: 7%;
    border: 1vw solid #8eca98;
    height: 10vw;
    width: 50%;
}
.minInputBlock, .secInputBlock{
    width: 50%;
}
.secInput{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ff9000;
    font-size: 10vw;
    border-radius: 7%;
    border: 1vw solid #8eca98;
    height: 10vw;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: input - изначально инлайновый элемент, ему писать в стилях `display:inline-block;` не нужно. А вот дивам, в которые ваши инпуты завёрнуты - такое свойство нужно, так как по-умолчанию. div - блочный элемент.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался